# Idiomatic C++ for remove_if

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this class

```
class Point2D
{
public:
 bool isValid();
 // ...
private:
 double x_, y_;
};
```

I have a `std::vector< Point2D >` and I would like to remove the invalid points, now I do like this:

```
bool invalid ( const Point2D& p )
{
 return !p.isValid();
}

void f()
{
 std::vector< Point2D > points;
 // fill points
 points.erase( std::remove_if( points.begin(), points.end(), invalid ), points.end() );
 // use valid points
}
```

Is there a standard way of doing this (beautifully), for example without the need of "duplicating" the functionality of the class method `Point2D::isValid`?

Maybe using C++11 lambda (I am not very familiar with lambda)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
points.erase(std::remove_if(points.begin(), 
                            points.end(),
                            std::not1(std::mem_fun_ref(&Point2D::isValid))), 
             points.end());
```

Answer (score 11):

Not totally standard but nearly : you can use boost::bind and do the following

```
points.erase( std::remove_if( points.begin(), points.end(),
  !boost::bind(&Point2D::isValid, _1 )), points.end() );
```

By the way you should declare the isValid method const.

Comment: +1 I prefer using bind over lambdas in this case, since you don't need to duplicate the signature. Since the OP seems to allow C++0x stuff, std::bind is probably a better choice tho.

Comment: I'm curious about what you mean by "won't really work". It's a documented feature (cf http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html) and I've used it previously without trouble

Comment: @ltjax This feature is not present for `std::bind`, it's Boost only.

Answer (score 10):

The lambda version won't be any cleaner either, but it has another important advantage: *locality*. You see the code where you use it:

```
points.erase( std::remove_if( points.begin(), points.end(),
              [](const Point2D& p){
                return !p.isValid();
              }), points.end() );
```

Note, that you need to change `isValid` to make it a `const` function, otherwise you can't call it on a reference-to-const (`const Point2D&`).
Another option would be to implement `operator!` for your class:

```
class Point2D{
  // ... as before
public:
  bool isValid() const;

  bool operator!() const{
    return !isValid();
  }
};
```

Note, both functions are const. Now you could implement a generic negating functor:

```
struct negate{
  template<class T>
  bool operator()(T const& t){
    return !t;
  }
};
```

And use that:

```
points.erase( std::remove_if( points.begin(), points.end(), negate()), points.end() );
```

Comment: Even though the answer is correct, I would advise *against* abusing operator overloading. At the very least, if used, it should be in conjunction with the Safe Bool Idiom.

Comment: @Matthieu M. +1 I agree, I do not like very much the operator overloading and I find "negate" not so readable in the remove_if

Comment: To extend on the comment of Matthieu M., see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool The c++11 standard gives an elegant solution by allowing explicit conversion operators.

Answer (score 6):

You can do what you want using a combination of [`std::mem_fun_ref`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun_ref/) and [`std::not1`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/not1/):

```
points.erase( std::remove_if( points.begin(), points.end(),
                              std::not1( std::mem_fun_ref( &Point2D::isValid ) ) ),
              points.end() );
```

For what it's worth, the only "idiomatic" part about this is the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Answer (score 5):

If Boost is OK for you, use what @Randall Flagg suggested together with [`boost::remove_erase_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/new/remove_erase_if.html):

```
boost::remove_erase_if(points, !boost::bind(&Point2D::isValid, _1));
```

Comment: @monkey: the first argument passed when the functor is called. In this case it is the `point` in consideration, which I want to bind to `this` so that bind is roughly equivalent to `!_1->Point2D::isValid()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`not1`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/not1/)

Edit: Looking at your example closer i don't think you can do it any other way, since `isValid()` is a member function.

Comment: That was my immediate reaction too!  But I don't think it's directly applicable here, because the OP wants to call a member function on the elements.

Comment: I think you can use `not1(mem_fun_ref(&Point2D::isValid))`.