# std::remove_if using other class method

Tags: c++, methods, stdvector, predicate, remove-if

I want to use `std::remove_if` with a predicate that is a member function of a differenct calss.

That is

```
class B;

class A {
    bool invalidB( const B& b ) const; // use members of class A to verify that B is invalid
    void someMethod() ;
};
```

Now, implementing `A::someMethod`, I have

```
void A::someMethod() {
    std::vector< B > vectorB; 
    // filling it with elements

    // I want to remove_if from vectorB based on predicate A::invalidB
    std::remove_if( vectorB.begin(), vectorB.end(), invalidB )
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I have already looked into the solution of
[Idiomatic C++ for remove_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263044/idiomatic-c-for-remove-if), but it deals with a slightly different case where the unary predicate of `remove_if` is a member of `B`and not `A`.

Moreover,
I do not have access to BOOST or c++11

Thanks!

Comment: Does your compiler implement TR1? If so, you can still use `std::tr1::bind`, which is exactly what you need here.

Comment: Any reason why it's not a `static` member function (or just not a member function at all)? That is, is there a specific `A` object you should be using to call `invalidB`?

Comment: can you make `InvalidD` static?

Comment: @sftrabbit I need information from a specific instance of `A` to determine if `B` is valid or not. It cannot be static.

Comment: use `bind1st` with `mem_fun` or `mem_fun_ref`

Comment: @BjörnPollex Even without TR1, this can be done with a combination of `mem_fun` and `bind1st`.  It's complicated enough, however, that it is usually simpler just to write your own functional object.

Comment: Oh, I just realised that `someMethod` is a member of `A`.

Comment: @JamesKanze - I'm afraid I do not follow you. Can you please be more specific on how `bind1st` and `mem_fun` can help me. I am unable to see how to use them to solve my problem

Comment: @Shai You can build up a functional object incrementally.  The syntax is unreadable enough that you don't want to know more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you're in `remove_if`, you've lost the `this` pointer of
`A`.  So you'll have to declare a functional object which holds
it, something like:

```
class IsInvalidB
{
    A const* myOwner;
public:
    IsInvalidB( A const& owner ) : myOwner( owner ) {}
    bool operator()( B const& obj )
    {
        return myOwner->invalidB( obj );
    }
}
```

Just pass an instance of this to `remove_if`.

Comment: Thanks, but I was kind of hoping to avoid declarations of additional functions/objects...

Comment: @Shai You can do it with `mem_fun` and `bind1st`, but I think you'll find that defining the additional object type is simpler.  (Having access to `std::bind` or lambdas changes the situation, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create additional functors and you're restricted to C++03, use `std::mem_fun_ref` and `std::bind1st`:

```
std::remove_if(vectorB.begin(), vectorB.end(),
               std::bind1st(std::mem_fun_ref(&A::invalidB), some_A));
```

Alternatively, if your compiler supports TR1, you can use `std::tr1::bind`:

```
using std::tr1::placeholders::_1;
std::remove_if(vectorB.begin(), vectorB.end(),
               std::tr1::bind(&A::invalidB, some_A, _1));
```

Comment: I get the following compile error: invalid redeclaration of member function "std::binder1st<_Fn2>::operator()(const std::unary_function<_Fn2::second_argument_type, _Fn2::result_type>::argument_type &) const [with _Fn2=std::const_mem_fun1_ref_t<bool, A, const B &>]"

Comment: PS - thank you for the answer. still not working, but I'm playing with it.

Comment: @Shai: this is a known defect in the standard library, ironically caused by fixing a different defect. This is the reason why `std::[tr1::]bind` was born, really.